# Makefile does not put .o files in build folder

Tags: c++, makefile

### Problem

I have the following structure of directories and files:

```
Makefile
main.cpp
|source
|-A.cpp
|-B.cpp
|-Linker.h
|build
```

And each file has this structure

**main.cpp**

```
//main.cpp
#include "source/Linker.h"

int main(){
    A(...)
    B(...)
}
```

**Linker.h**

```
//Linker.h
void A
void B
```

**A.cpp**
**B.cpp**
each defines a specific function.

What I like to do is, to build this structure using `Makefile` and **put all the `.o` files inside the `build` directory**.

---

### What I tried

So I made the following `Makefile`:

```
CC = g++ -std=c++11
CFLAGS = -c -Wall

OBJS = ./build/main.o ./build/A.o ./build/B.o 
OUT  = Project

all: Project

Project: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o Project

./build/main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp

./build/A.o: ./source/A.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) ./source/A.cpp

./build/B.o: ./source/B.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) ./source/B.cpp
```

---

### Error

But this produces all the `.o` files in the top directory, with the following error:

```
g++: error: ./build/main.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./build/A.o: No such file or directory
g++: error: ./build/B.o: No such file or directory
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: You need to specify an output path for the object file to be compiled. This is the `-o build/A.o` option for example (`gcc` and `clang`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler tells you that the output directory with those `.o` files doesn't exist.

A fix is to make targets depend on their directory and specify the output files explicitly (with `-o $@`):

```
Project: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJS) 

build/%.o: %.cpp | build
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<

build/%.o: source/%.cpp | build
    $(CC) -o $@ $(CFLAGS) $<

build:
    mkdir $@
```

Note that the above uses one pattern rule to build all of your `.o` files.

---

Normally, `CXX` is used for C++ compiler along with `CXXFLAGS`. `CC` and `CFLAGS` are used for building C code.

Comment: Although the answer is correct, it is missing the explanation of the error, that is the compilation commands are missing the output targets (-o option).

Comment: @MeherKhiari Read sentence 2 in the answer.